# BooleanBinding and TimeLine

Tags: java, javafx

I've got a BooleanBinding, which looks like this:

```
    public void initQueue(ObservableList<Player> players) {
        queueIsFree = new BooleanBinding() {
            {
            players.forEach(
                player -> bind(player.getRobot().animatingProperty));
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean computeValue() {
            Boolean bool = true;
            for (Player p : players) {
                if (p.getRobot().animatingProperty.get() == true) {
                bool = false;
                break;
                }
            }
            return bool;
            }

        };

   }
```

It is supposed to be true, when all of the animatingProperties of the Robots are false. As soon as one of them changes, this changeListener is called:

```
change = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
        Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        if (newValue.equals(true)) {
          if (list.size() > 0) {
        // plays the next animation, which, when finished, sets the animatingProperty back to false
                nextAnimation();
            } else {
                stopQueue();
            }
        }

       }

};
```

**Problem**: the valueChangedEvent fires so often, that i get a stackOverFlowError.

In order to animate, i use a TimeLine and an AnimationTimer, i suppose that this is the problem, yet i don't know how to solve it.

**Edit**: I know now, that the Problem is, that TimeLines are asynchronous, meaning, that they start and then the next line of code is executed, which means, that the booleanBinding, that i've created is useless.
I'll have to think of another way to play my animations one after another.

Comment: you cannot get stack overflow exception because something is called too often, you can get it only if it calls itself recursively

Comment: Okay, i understand. Well it is supposed to call itself recursively, but only after the animation is finished (timeline.setOnFinished(..)) and that until the list is empty.